OpenAPI management in multi app environments
In a project we have multiple apps where (almost) each provides own and consumes other openapiAPI spec files. Right now each app has a copy of the openAPI spec files both provided and consumed which forces us to update the same file in multiple locations when openAPI spec files change. We have the code generation (client and server) implemented in the build process (maven, openapi-generator-maven-plugin). We find these multiple updates to be difficult to maintain over time and error-prone.
Besides creating a mono repo, what else can we do to manage the openAPI spec files in, say, a single location and make them available to every app's build process?

I think an API catalog could help here. When an application changes its OpenAPI description, it publishes to the catalog. When any other application needs an OpenAPI description, it fetches it from the catalog. Some tools are standalone, others are part of internal developer platforms, but something like that could maybe be helpful in this situation.

Thanks for your answer. That sounds promising. Can you elaborate on standalone tools? Is there something that we could integrate with our self hosted gitlab instance?
